# My C data structure isn't working properly

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

I'm a Computer Engineering student in Brazil and I'm having Algorithms and Data Structure classes this semester. The subject I'm having now is "Generic Trees". I have an activity to simulate a cmd like program, and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0
 
typedef int bool;
 
typedef struct No {
    char nome[1025];
 
    struct No *primFilho;
    struct No *proxIrmao;
    struct No *pai;
} No;

typedef struct TipoRaiz {
    No *raiz;
} TipoRaiz;
 
int contador = 0;
 
No *CriaNovoNo(char nome[1025]) {
    No *novoNo = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));

    strcpy(novoNo->nome, nome);
    novoNo->primFilho = NULL;
    novoNo->proxIrmao = NULL;
    novoNo->pai = NULL;
    
    return novoNo;
}
 
void inicializa(TipoRaiz *raiz) {
    raiz->raiz = CriaNovoNo("\\root");
}
 
void printTree(No *root, int depth) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
 
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        printf("  "); 
        
    printf("%s\n", root->nome);
 
    printTree(root->primFilho, depth + 1); 
    printTree(root->proxIrmao, depth);    
}

No *buscaNo(char nome[], No *raiz) {
    if (raiz == NULL)
        return NULL;
        
    if (strcmp(raiz->nome, nome) == 0)
        return raiz;
    No *p = raiz->primFilho;
    while (p) {
        No *resp = buscaNo(nome, p);
        if (resp)
            return resp;
        p = p->proxIrmao;
    }
    
    return NULL;
}
 
void insere(TipoRaiz *root, char novoNo[], char localPai[]) {
    No *pai = buscaNo(localPai, root->raiz);
    if (pai == NULL) 
        return;
        
    No *inserido = CriaNovoNo(novoNo);
    inserido->pai = pai;
    if (pai->primFilho == NULL) {
        pai->primFilho = inserido;
    } else {
        inserido->proxIrmao = pai->primFilho;
        pai->primFilho = inserido;
    }

    contador++;
}

void removeNo(No *no) {
    No *p = no->pai;
    No *q = no->primFilho;

    if (p != NULL) {
        if (p->primFilho == no)
            p->primFilho = no->proxIrmao;
        else {
            while(q->proxIrmao != no) {
                q = q->proxIrmao;
            }
            q->proxIrmao = no->proxIrmao;
        }
        free(no);
    }
}
 
void printCaminho(No* no) {
    No* pilha[contador];
    int top = -1;
 
    while (no != NULL) {
        pilha[++top] = no;
        no = no->pai;
    }    

    while (top >= 0) {
        printf("%s ", pilha[top--]->nome);
    }
}
 
int main() {
    TipoRaiz root;

    inicializa(&root);
    int n;
    char nome[1025], localPai[1025], comando[3], buscado[1025];
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%s", buscado);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s %s %s", comando, nome, localPai);

        if (strcmp(comando, "-a") == 0) 
            insere(&root, nome, localPai);
        else if (strcmp(comando,"-r") == 0) {
            No *noParaRemover = buscaNo(nome, &root);
            removeNo(noParaRemover);
        }
        else if (strcmp(comando, "-m") == 0) {
            if (buscaNo(localPai, &root)) {
                No *noParaMover = buscaNo(nome, &root);
                removeNo(noParaMover);
                insere(&root, nome, localPai);
            }
        }
    }
 
    // used for debugging purposes printTree(root.raiz, 0);
    
    No *buscadoNo = buscaNo(buscado, root.raiz);
    if (buscadoNo == NULL)
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado!\n");
    else {
        printCaminho(buscadoNo);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have 10 entries that will be tested for my code, but in only 2 entries, I'm having problems, that are probably in my `insere` function, that inserts a new node in the tree, or in my `remove` function, that removes the node from the tree. The first entry gives me a Time Limit Exceeded and I do not know how to optimize the code to make it run faster, and the next one, gives me a wrong output, here are the tests (feel free to fix any more bugs that you find in my code):

Input number 1 (Time limit error):

```
30
file8
-a \dir1 \root
-a \dir2 \root
-a \dir3 \root
-a \dir4 \root
-a \dir5 \root
-a \dir6 \root
-a \dir7 \root
-a \dir8 \root
-a \dir9 \root
-a \dir10 \root
-a file1 \root
-a file2 \root
-a file3 \root
-a file4 \root
-a file5 \root
-a file6 \root
-a file7 \root
-a file8 \root
-a file9 \root
-a file10 \root
-r file1
-r file3
-r file5
-r file7
-r file9
-r file2
-r file6
-r file10
-r file4
-m file8 \dir10
```

The output 1 should be:

```
file8 \dir10 \root
```

Input number 2:

```
134
arq10
-a \dir1 \root
-a \dir2 \dir1
-a \dir3 \dir2
-a \dir4 \dir3
-a \dir5 \dir4
-a \dir6 \dir5
-a \dir7 \dir6
-a \dir8 \dir7
-a \dir9 \dir8
-a \dir10 \dir9
-a \dir11 \dir10
-a \dir12 \dir11
-a \dir13 \dir12
-a \dir14 \dir13
-a \dir15 \dir14
-a \dir16 \dir15
-a \dir17 \dir16
-a \dir18 \dir17
-a \dir19 \dir18
-a arq1 \dir1
-a arq2 \dir2
-a arq3 \dir3
-a arq4 \dir4
-a arq5 \dir5
-a arq6 \dir6
-a arq7 \dir7
-a arq8 \dir8
-a arq9 \dir9
-a arq10 \dir10
-a arq11 \dir11
-a arq12 \dir12
-a arq13 \dir13
-a arq14 \dir14
-a arq15 \dir15
-a arq16 \dir16
-a arq17 \dir17
-a arq18 \dir18
-a arq19 \dir19
-a \pasta1 \root
-a \pasta2 \pasta1
-a \pasta3 \pasta2
-a \pasta4 \pasta3
-a \pasta5 \pasta4
-a \pasta6 \pasta5
-a \pasta7 \pasta6
-a \pasta8 \pasta7
-a \pasta9 \pasta8
-a \pasta10 \pasta9
-a \pasta11 \pasta10
-a \pasta12 \pasta11
-a \pasta13 \pasta12
-a \pasta14 \pasta13
-a \pasta15 \pasta14
-a \pasta16 \pasta15
-a \pasta17 \pasta16
-a \pasta18 \pasta17
-a \pasta19 \pasta18
-m arq1 \pasta1
-m arq2 \pasta2
-m arq3 \pasta3
-m arq4 \pasta4
-m arq5 \pasta5
-m arq6 \pasta6
-m arq7 \pasta7
-m arq8 \pasta8
-m arq9 \pasta9
-m arq10 \pasta10
-m arq11 \pasta11
-m arq12 \pasta12
-m arq13 \pasta13
-m arq14 \pasta14
-m arq15 \pasta15
-m arq16 \pasta16
-m arq17 \pasta17
-m arq18 \pasta18
-m arq19 \pasta19
-a \novo1 \root
-a \novo2 \novo1
-a \novo3 \novo2
-a \novo4 \novo3
-a \novo5 \novo4
-a \novo6 \novo5
-a \novo7 \novo6
-a \novo8 \novo7
-a \novo9 \novo8
-a \novo10 \novo9
-a \novo11 \novo10
-a \novo12 \novo11
-a \novo13 \novo12
-a \novo14 \novo13
-a \novo15 \novo14
-a \novo16 \novo15
-a \novo17 \novo16
-a \novo18 \novo17
-a \novo19 \novo18
-m arq1 \nova1
-m arq2 \nova2
-m arq3 \nova3
-m arq4 \nova4
-m arq5 \nova5
-m arq6 \nova6
-m arq7 \nova7
-m arq8 \nova8
-m arq9 \nova9
-m arq10 \nova10
-m arq11 \nova11
-m arq12 \nova12
-m arq13 \nova13
-m arq14 \nova14
-m arq15 \nova15
-m arq16 \nova16
-m arq17 \nova17
-m arq18 \nova18
-m arq19 \nova19
-r arq1
-r arq2
-r arq3
-r arq4
-r arq5
-r arq6
-r arq7
-r arq8
-r arq9
-r arq10
-r arq11
-r arq12
-r arq13
-r arq14
-r arq15
-r arq16
-r arq17
-r arq18
-r arq19
-a arq10 \root
```

The output number 2 should be:

```
arq10 \root
```

Comment: Your program is not using English so that makes it harder for us to help you.  What output are you getting?

Comment: Always use a maximum field with when reading  strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: Avoid global variables when possible (`int contador`).  It complicates testing & reuse.

Comment: Check the return value from `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.

Comment: Your program does _not_ compile cleanly. There are three places where you call `buscaNo` with args like `buscaNo(nome,&root);` But, `&root` is a `TipoRaiz *` pointer. But, you have `No *buscaNo(char nome[],No *raiz)` so the second argument should be a `No *` pointer and _not_ a `TipoRaiz *` pointer. You probably want `root.raiz` as the second argument.

Comment: After applying the fix I mentioned, using your first input file, the program segfaults in the `removeNo` function on the line: `while (q->proxIrmao != no)` because `q` is `NULL`. This is the _first_ call to `removeNo` so `no->pai` is non-null, but `no->primFilho` _is_ null. If this is null, do you just want to exit the function (because there is nothing to remove)?

Comment: After simply checking for `if (q != NULL) { ... }`, the program runs to completion, but the output is `\root file8`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, your code uses non-English variables and comments. This makes it hard to understand your program. I'd either translate the symbols to English and repost here. Or, try the Portuguese SO site: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `main()`: As @CraigEstey explained `buscaNo()`'s 2nd argument is a `No *` but you pass it `&root` which is a `TipoRaiz *`.  I didn't do it below but I suggest you eliminate the `TipoRaiz` type.  Resolve all compiler warnings; if you didn't get one here turn up the warning levels.
2. `removeNo()` segfaults.  You need to start the search for the previous node at `No *q = p->primFilho;` then walk the linked list `q = q->proxIrmao`.
3. `printCaminho()` prints the result in reverse order.  Rewrote the function to follow `pai` to the root and pulled the non-existing result into the function to simplify `main()`.
4. Eliminate the global variable `contador`.
5. `main()`: The 2nd input fails because you expect each line to contain 3 words but the `-r` command only contains 2.  Read a line with `fgets()` (or `getline()`) then use `sscanf()` to parse either 2 or 3 fields from that line.  I didn't do it below but I suggest that you always check the return value of `scanf()` and `sscanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
6. Always specify a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.
7. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values (1025, 3).  It makes it easier to change your program, say, you decide that you only need 32 bytes instead then it's one place to change it and all the uses including the derived for `line` just works.
8. (Not fixed) Memory leaks.
9. Don't cast the `void *` from `malloc()`.
10. Prefer using the variable name instead of the type to `sizeof`.  You end up repeating yourself less that way `struct foo *bar = malloc(sizeof *bar)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COMMAND_LEN 2
#define LEN 1024
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

typedef struct No {
    char nome[LEN+1];
    struct No *primFilho;
    struct No *proxIrmao;
    struct No *pai;
} No;

typedef struct TipoRaiz {
    No *raiz;
} TipoRaiz;

No *CriaNovoNo(char *nome) {
    No *novoNo = malloc(sizeof *novoNo);
    strcpy(novoNo->nome, nome);
    novoNo->primFilho = NULL;
    novoNo->proxIrmao = NULL;
    novoNo->pai = NULL;
    return novoNo;
}

void inicializa(TipoRaiz *raiz) {
    raiz->raiz = CriaNovoNo("\\root");
}

void printTree(No *root, int depth) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        printf("  ");
    printf("%s\n", root->nome);
    printTree(root->primFilho, depth + 1);
    printTree(root->proxIrmao, depth);
}

No *buscaNo(char nome[], No *raiz) {
    if(raiz == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(strcmp(raiz->nome, nome) == 0)
        return raiz;
    No *p = raiz->primFilho;
    while(p) {
        No *resp = buscaNo(nome, p);
        if(resp)
            return resp;
        p = p->proxIrmao;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void insere(TipoRaiz *root, char *novoNo, char *localPai) {
    No *pai = buscaNo(localPai, root->raiz);
    if(!pai)
        return;
    No *inserido = CriaNovoNo(novoNo);
    inserido->pai = pai;
    if(pai->primFilho)
        inserido->proxIrmao = pai->primFilho;
    pai->primFilho = inserido;
}

void removeNo(No *no) {
    No *p = no->pai;
    if(!p)
        return;
    if(p->primFilho == no)
        p->primFilho = no->proxIrmao;
    else {
        No *q = p->primFilho;
        for(; q->proxIrmao != no; q = q->proxIrmao);
        q->proxIrmao = no->proxIrmao;
    }
    free(no);
}

void printCaminho(No* no) {
    if(!no) {
        printf("Arquivo nao encontrado!\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%s", no->nome);
    for(no = no->pai; no; no = no->pai)
        printf(" %s", no->nome);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    TipoRaiz root;
    inicializa(&root);
    int n;
    char nome[LEN+1];
    char localPai[LEN+1];
    char comando[COMMAND_LEN+1];
    char buscado[LEN+1];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%" str(LEN) "s", buscado);
    getchar();
    char line[COMMAND_LEN+2*LEN+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            printf("input missing\n");
            return 1;
        }
        sscanf(line, "%" str(COMMAND_LEN) "s %" str(LEN) "s %" str(LEN) "s", comando, nome, localPai);
        if(!strcmp(comando, "-a") )
            insere(&root, nome, localPai);
        else if(!strcmp(comando,"-r")) {
            No *noParaRemover = buscaNo(nome, root.raiz);
            removeNo(noParaRemover);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(comando, "-m")) {
            if(buscaNo(localPai, root.raiz)) {
                No *noParaMover = buscaNo(nome, root.raiz);
                removeNo(noParaMover);
                insere(&root, nome, localPai);
            }
        }
    }
    printCaminho(buscaNo(buscado, root.raiz));
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
$ ./your_homework < input_1.txt
file8 \dir10 \root
$ ./your_homework < input_2.txt
arq10 \root
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the portuguese variables, I'll change them to english next time.

Comment: My pleasure.  We just want to help you get the most help here.

Comment: Also ask one question per submission.  Submit multiple questions if needed.  Hard-coding a failing test case (i.e. no external input)  is a great way to communicate what the input is, what you expect and what you actually get.